# Pandas : saving Series of dictionaries to disk

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a python pandas Series of dictionaries :

```
id           dicts
1            {'5': 1, '8': 20, '1800': 2}
2            {'2': 2, '8': 1, '1000': 25, '1651': 1}
...          ...
...          ...
...          ...
20000000     {'2': 1, '10': 20}
```

The (key, value) in the dictionaries represent ('feature', count). About 2000 unique features exist.

The Series' memory usage in pandas is about 500MB. 
What would be the best way to write this object to disk (having ideally low disk space usage, and being fast to write and fast to read back in afterwards) ?

Options considered (and tried for the first 2) :
- to_csv (but treats the dictionaries as strings, so conversion back to dictionaries afterwards is very slow)
- cPickle (but ran out of memory during execution)
- conversion to a scipy sparse matrix structure

Comment: Regarding disk space, `to_csv()` does have a compression argument, e.g., `to_csv(..., compression = 'gzip')`. More generally, a tool you may want to look into in is [Blaze](https://github.com/blaze/blaze). You can convert a pandas data structure into a blaze ds and manipulate it using blaze's pandas-like API. The main advantage is that blaze does not load all the data into memory, like pandas.

Comment: Do you still run out of memory if you use the `to_pickle` method on the `Series`?  In general storing dictionaries in rows isn't great in `pandas` - it's basically no different that keeping them in a built in list - this does seem like a case for some kind of sparse array?

Comment: @InNoam The problem with the csv is that restoring the dicts afterwards (using eval()) is slow and runs out of memory in my case. Will look into Blaze !

Comment: Why would you put dictionaries in a Series?

Comment: @chrisb True, this could just as well be a list of dicts (thought that would lose the Series' index, which might be relevant). Still gives a Memory Error. Btw, the file created on disk is over 3GB at the time the MemError stops the process.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because the index could be relevant. The question could apply to a list of dicts as well, which would face the same challenge...

Comment: @SLeon Do you expect a wide range of values for each feature? Or can you be confident they will be below some value? I ask because it is possible even a non-sparse data-structure would be more memory efficient than a Series of 20,000,000  dicts. Each dict object requires, at minimum (i.e. when it is empty)   288 bytes. That's orders of magnitude larger than a 32 bit integer. And that isn't counting that a dict is storing Python ints, which are objects, which require pretty large memory overhead too, and the key's which will be strings. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am confident they're integers, but they could be large (lets say max 10**6)

Comment: @Darn. Then you'd likely be better off using a sparse structure.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Dense matrix of 20 million rows, 2000 features and 32-bit integers would require 160 GB (approximately). That wouldn't make sense -)

Comment: I'm not certain it will be any be any better than pickle, but `to_msgback` would be another option for round-trip-able serialization that supports dicts.

Comment: @SLeon yeah I realized my mental math was off :). Im currently on my cellphone, but check out this link http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious as to how your `Series` only takes up 500MB. If you are using the `.memory_usage` method, this will only return the total memory used by the each python object reference, which is all your Series is storing. That doesn't account for the actual memory of the dictionaries. Rough calculation 20,000,000 * 288 bytes = 5.76GB should be your memory usage. That 288 bytes is a conservative estimate of the memory required by each dictionary.

### Converting to a sparse matrix

Anyway, try the following approach to convert your data into a sparse-matrix representation:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import pickle
```

I would use `int`s rather than strings as keys, as this will keep the right order later on. So, assuming your series is named `dict_series`:

```
dict_series = dict_series.apply(lambda d: {int(k):d[k] for k in d}
```

This might be memory intensive, and you maybe be better off simply creating your `Series` of `dict`s using `int`s as keys from the start. Or simply you can just skip this step. Now, to construct your sparse matrix:

```
dv = DictVectorizer(dtype=np.int32)
sparse = dv.fit_transform(dict_series)
```

### Saving to disk

Now, essentially, your sparse matrix can be reconstructed from 3 fields: `sparse.data`, `sparse.indices`, `sparse.indptr`, an optionally, `sparse.shape`. The fastest and most memory efficient way to save an load the arrays `sparse.data`, `sparse.indices`, `sparse.indptr` is to use the np.ndarray `tofile` method, which saves the arrays as raw bytes. From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

> This is a convenience function for quick storage of array data.
>   Information on endianness and precision is lost, so this method is not
>   a good choice for files intended to archive data or transport data
>   between machines with different endianness.

So this method loses any dtype information and  endiamness. The former issue can be dealt with simply by making note of the datatype before hand, you'll be using np.int32 anyway. The latter issue isn't a problem if you are working locally, but if portability is important, you will need to look into alternate ways of storing the information.

```
# to save
sparse.data.tofile('data.dat')
sparse.indices.tofile('indices.dat')
sparse.indptr.tofile('indptr.dat')
# don't forget your dict vectorizer!
with open('dv.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dv,f) # pickle your dv to be able to recover your original data!
```

### To recover everything:

```
with open('dv.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    dv = pickle.load(f)

sparse = csr_matrix((np.fromfile('data.dat', dtype = np.int32),
                     np.fromfile('indices.dat', dtype = np.int32),
                     np.fromfile('indptr.dat', dtype = np.int32))

original = pd.Series(dv.inverse_transform(sparse))
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Indeed, I wrongly used the `.memory_usage` method. Your answer allowed to store the whole object on disk in less than 700MB. The `inverse_transform` method was very slow for me, so I decided to do the required operations directly on the csr_matrix (using the `.vocabulary_` attribute of the DictVectorizer to keep track of the mapping between features and columns)

Comment: @SLeon Glad I could be of help. I'm curious, did the original transform take long? I only every tried this out with toy examples.

Comment: The `fit_transform` runs reasonably fast, the `inverse_transform` very slowly.