# The best way of python saving and loading data in terms of space and speed

Tags: python, save, load, space

I have a three dimension array (96660, 45243, 2) generated in python which I want to save and load it later on in another python code, I used .pny format, it takes up 66G, and loading is very slow. There are three question:

- If the data is dense what is the best way of saving it in terms
  storage?
- If the data is sparse, what is the best way?
- How to feed the sparse data to Tensor flow? seems there is tf.sparse.placeholder option but after feeding the value, thecalculation on the graph is giving me error,

Comment: You have a ton of data. You're going to need a ton of space. If it's sparse or compressible, you could get away with less, but first you need to understand why it's taking all that space in the first place.

Comment: What is .pny format? Do you mean .npy? Are you working with `numpy.ndarray` objects containing numerical data? Likely, the best way is to use [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). If you have a sparse-matrix, let's call it `sparse`, you'll have to save and reload three numpy objects, the `sparse.data`, the `sparse.indices`, and the `sparse.indptr`, from which, you can reconstruct your sparse-matrix object.

Comment: @user2357112  it is numpy.ndarray, I saved by using numpy.save, then the file takes that big space. I do not know why it takes that big space, only reason I can think of is the size (96660, 45243, 2)  is huge ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hmm, yes, it is numpy.ndarrat, saved by using numpy.save.  It is sparse, only concern I have is that is the reconstruction take long? and also transferring to dense would also take long if I need later on the dense version?

Comment: @aminamollaysa when you say it is sparse, do you mean you are working with some kind of [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) object? If not, and your `numpy.ndarray` is sparse, as in, lots of 0's, then you could probably get *significant space-saving* by working with a `scipy.sparse` object. Reconstructing a sparse matrix object will be much faster than your dense `np.ndarray`  if it is truly sparse, however, conversion might take some time, although, it is down to specifics how badly that might affect things

Comment: 96k * 45k * 2 is the number of elements you have. For 8 bytes per element and that's 65 GB + tax.

Comment: @aminamollaysa check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621539/pandas-saving-series-of-dictionaries-to-disk/38625568#38625568) to a sort-of unrelated question. It does, however, show how to save and reconstruct a sparse-matrix. Note, I used the `tofile` and `fromfile` convenience methods, but the principle should be the same with `np.save` and `np.load`, and you should use those because the `.npy` format is *much preferable* for reproducibility and portability.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, it has a lot of 0's and you can transfer to `scipy.sparse`, hmm, I think later on I need to convert to dense matrix, is there any other way of saving the data in the first place with less space?

Comment: @aminamollaysa yes, save the sparse matrix in the way I show in that link.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` only works with less or equal to two dimensional array?

Comment: For 2-d arrays only

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The array I have above is 3D